# position: sticky content disappear and element disappear when over scrolling on iOS safari

Tags: html, css, safari

there is a `position: sticky` element on top, which content is overflowed. when over scrolling the page, something wired happend

In the beginning, content of sticky element disappeared.

and then, sticky element disappeared

*can anybody explain this*

---

[screen record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JczGx.gif)

or you can try this [example](https://kwokkwok.github.io/gitpage/) by yourself

source:

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="tabs">
      <div class="item">101vw sticky</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<style>
  .main {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .tabs {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
  .item {
    width: 101vw;
  }
</style>
```